# In TypeScript, can I restrict type of indexer value based on narrow type of indexer key?

Tags: typescript

Simple example (type of `x`):

```js
const x = {
    'a': { key: 'a' },
    'b': { key: 'b' },
    'c': { key: 'c' },
    // ...
};
```

If I knew all `a`/`b`/`c`/`…` in advance, I could do `{ [TKey in 'a'|'b'|'c']: { key: TKey } }`.

But can I define a type so that for any key `k` value must have `{ key: k }` without having a full list of keys in advance?

Answer (score 0):

You can let the compiler message guide you:

This is what you would like:

```
type Foo<K> = { [TKey in K]: { key: TKey } }
```

but it doesn't compile because

```
Type 'K' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
  Type 'K' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
```

Assuming (based on your example) you want to work only with string keys:

```
type Foo<K extends string> = { [TKey in K]: { key: TKey } }
```

So you can pass your own narrowed type that's based on string:

```
type X = Foo<'a' | 'b' | 'c'>
```

```
type X = {
    a: {
        key: "a";
    };
    b: {
        key: "b";
    };
    c: {
        key: "c";
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That only works if I know `<'a' | 'b' | 'c'>` in advance, when creating type `X`. What if I don't? For example, what if I am doing `export const x = { ... }` and other modules can import it and add their own values?

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for this as well. I experimented in TypeScript a bit and came up with this solution:

```
type ObjectWithKey<obj extends {[key: string]: any}> = {
  [k in keyof obj]: {key: k};
}

declare function createObjectWithKeys<T extends {[key: string]: any} & ObjectWithKey<T>>(input: T): T;

// This does not compile
const x = createObjectWithKeys({
    a: 1,
    b: {key: 'c'},
    c: {key: false}
})

// This does compile
const x = createObjectWithKeys({
    a: {key: 'a'},
    b: {key: 'b'},
    c: {key: 'c'}
})
```